# TFS build controller does not support xcopy [source] [destination] /e

Tags: windows, visual-studio, tfs, cmd, build

I am facing an issue when trying to generate build. I have post deploy batch command where I am copying files and folder using xcopy.

This doesn't seem to work.

Is there any solution or work around for this.

Comment: please show errors and the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On TFS and VSTS you should use the Copy Files task provided.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/copy-files

Just drop the task onto the execution stuck and configure it as per the documentation.

You will still not be able to access disc location outside of the agent permission scope.